# Ubuntu freezes when connecting external audio interface

Tags: usb, sound

AskUbuntu! Newbie here.

When I connect either my Scarlette 2i2, or my headset USB
interface, at first nothing happens. When I either suspend or log out,
my mouse freezes. Sometimes the keyboard as well.
I've had to restart by using the reset button on my case.
Could this be a problem with my mobos USB controller?
Tried both the front panel USB ports and the
ones on the back, no luck.

Edit: broken front panel usb hub!

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, similiar problems have been reported on this version.

Comment: I asked what OS & release you are using, not what OS (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) it is reported as *reported on*  (though any reported bug reports you've made on launchpad would be useful)